# angular material sidenav not working as expected in fixed div

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to do the following but having some problems, this plunk shows what im trying to do: https://plnkr.co/bCMKRr , there are just two typescript files, the md content is in `mainContent.component.html`:

```
<md-sidenav-container>

<md-sidenav #sidenav class="example-sidenav2" align="end" mode="over">
</md-sidenav>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

Ive got a top navbar that is fixed, and a left navbar that is also fixed, then ive got the main content in the space left.

In that main content, ive got some buttons that will open a material sidenav on the right, the content of this material sidenav will be different due to which button is pressed.

Right now it scrolls with the main content when opened. I want it to open and when it scrolls down, the sidenav content scrolls but the main content doesnt scroll.

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get sidenev out of container

```
 <md-sidenav-container>

<div >
   some long contents
</div>
</md-sidenav-container>
<md-sidenav #sidenav class="example-sidenav2" align="end" mode="over">
```

[Here is working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QPy8QLIaeZq47L4SSwJm?p=preview)

Comment: I see what you did and it did work, but not quite exactly what I want to happen. I just updated the plunker with a few changes, When the sidenav is open, hovering over the sidenav you can scroll the sidenav to the true length of its content, the main-content itself doesnt scroll. but hovering over the main content, the div containing the component shifts past the header and to the top of the browser window, once there it does not scroll anymore. My aim is if hovering over the main-content, there is absolutly no scroll. If there is no header then it works fine, but I really need the header.

Comment: I have updated the plunker and answer see if it works for you

Comment: You helped me to understand the problem better, but your plunk still scrolls past the header, my answer with the plunk shows no scroll on the main content but with full scroll on the sidebar

Comment: are you looking for something like https://plnkr.co/edit/XiRo7lpy1coqcH4deynJ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the solution, it was a combination of certain classes for the divs and the corresponding css styles. The new plunk at https://plnkr.co/IiidRr contains the code exactly working how I want it to.

The most notable change that got the effect was to define the div containing the component as

```
position: fixed;
```

and it not to have:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```